# for loop on a "wp_query" object in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, for-loop

I need to check if any of the children items of the next object have children themselves.
I thought to do it with a for loop but I am not sure how to go about it.

The object is as below:

```
$children = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'page', 'post_parent'=>get_the_ID(), 'post_status'=>'publish','orderby'=>'menu_order','order'=>'ASC'));
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$children = get_posts( 
    array(
        'post_type'=>'page', 
        'post_parent'=> get_the_ID(), 
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'orderby'=>'menu_order',
        'order'=>'ASC'
    )
); 

foreach ( $children as $child ) {

    $has_kids = wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&child_of=' . $child->ID );

    if ($has_kids) {
        echo $child->post_title . " has children.";
    } else {
        echo $child->post_title . " doesn't have children.";
    }

}
```